# Wait for all Queue events done?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-11-alexandria

When running a function asynchronously in the main thread, like

```
TThread::CurrentThread->Queue(NULL, somefunction);
```

before closing my app I'd like to make sure all events have finished. But all I can find is a way to remove pending events

```
TThread::CurrentThread->RemoveQueuedEvents(somefunction);
```

How do I wait for them to finish instead of removing all?

Comment: FYI, `Queue()` has a `static` overload, so you don't need to use `CurrentThread` to call it: `TThread::Queue(NULL, somefunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the RTL doesn't really provide a mechanism to do what you are asking for, at least not directly.

You can try using a thread-safe counter that is incremented each time a function is queued, and decremented each time a queued function exits. Then, the main thread can call [`CheckSynchronize()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) in a loop until that counter reaches 0.

Or, you can simply terminate all of your worker threads, make sure they are *fully* terminated, and then just call `CheckSynchronize()` 1 time to process the final queue since nothing would be adding new entries to it anymore.

Comment: I already tried your first solution, but the code just did not sit right with me. Your second solution sounds interesting, but I don't think that'll work as I have multiple threads adding to the queue, which in turn updates a TMemo (logging). I prefer to let all events finish (instead of removing them) before destroying the memo.

Comment: I wonder who thought of writing a Remove but not a WaitFor.. Anyway, valid answer so thanks.

Comment: My 1st suggestion can be made easier/cleaner using some helper wrappers around the functions, so the functions themselves don't have to worry about the counter. My 2nd suggestion will process whatever is in the queue, you would just stop the threads first so the queue doesn't change anymore.